# Only bottom tableviewcell background being edited

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

Only the bottom cell of my UITableView is being edited when i change the backgroundView. I want the same background for each cell. But top 3 are white and last one is the image. I dont know why this is. Here is my code under the tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

}

[cell setBackgroundView:backgroundImage];
[cell.detailTextLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15]];
[cell.detailTextLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10]];
[cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];

cell.detailTextLabel.text = [packArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
cell.textLabel.text = @"Soleternity Productions";
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
cell.textLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor grayColor];
cell.detailTextLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor grayColor];
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

return cell;
```

Comment: "Only the bottom cell of my UITableView is being edited" - do you mean only one cell is refreshed? try reloading the other cells. [table reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept is simple. If you add a view `X` as a *subView* of another view `A`, then `A` will contain the view `X`. Later, if you add the same view `X` to some other view `B`, then `X` will be first removed from `A` and added to `B`. That is what happening here.

Here , you are having a view `backgroundImage` and assigning it as the `backgroundView` of all the cells. So, obviously the lastly assigned cell will contain the `backgroundImage`.

You have to create new views in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method and assign it to the current cell.

```
UIImageView *backgroundImage = ...
// Configure backgroundImage
[cell setBackgroundView:backgroundImage];
```

Comment: That makes sense. So what should i do then? Create 4 imageViews and assign them all separately?

Comment: You create the view inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method itself. See my updated answer.

Comment: alright that sounds like itll work. Thanks ill give it a try!